# Quantify how good is a object detection in image processing

Tags: image-processing, video-processing, kalman-filter

I developed Oil&Gas pipeline detector, which works fairly well. The detector outputs is a line that represents the pipe position in respect to the camera.

Although it has very low false-positive rate, I would like to quantify how reliable is my detection. So I can provide it to other components that receives the line information.

Initially I started to compute the standard deviation of the last 10 samples, which gave me a good starting point, since when a false positive is detected, the std deviation increases. However since the camera moves over time this metric not reliable, because the movement itself would increase the value.

I have camera velocities information, so I thought I could kind of fuse the "predicted" measurement with the detected, with a Kalman Filter, for instance. The filter covariances would give the estimation I want.

Edited to add more relevant information:

- Single camera with known parameters and fixed local length.
- The camera is attached to a robot's body.
- Camera moves with low velocities (max: 0.5 m/s max and 0.3 rad/s).
- The detector output is the line angle and shorter distance camera-line meters.

However I'm not sure if Kalman filter is the right/best technique to apply here. Does anyone have any suggestion how I can handle this?

Comment: I think more information is needed to determine the best method for this. For instance, does the system use a single camera with known parameters? Fixed focal length? Is the camera hand held or attached to a machine? How much is the camera moving? How is the output displayed (numbers, graphic)? I suspect that the Kalman filter might not be the right fit for your needs. I'd lean toward correlating the projection of each image if the relative camera positions are known and calculating the variation between the two.

Comment: Single camera with know parameters, fixed local length. It is attached to a robot body. Camera moves with low velocities (max. 0.3 rad/s max. 0.5 m/s). The output is number (line angle and distance to line). I'll edit the question to add these information. Thx! – dbcesar 6 mins ago